# I am working on finding the min value in a random array, and anyone know that why my code is not working? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, min

Here's what I did.
I am working on find the min value in a random array, 
Anyone know that why my code is not working?
It output with lowest valus : 0 and located on a complex number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,min,n;
    int array[1000];
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
        {
        x = rand()% 1000 + 1;
        array[i] = x;
        }
    min=array[0];
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {       
            if(array[i]<min) 
            {   
                min=array[i];
                n=i;
            }
        }
        cout<<"The Lowest Value : "<<min<<"\nIts located at { "<< n <<" }"<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the first loop, array[i] = x; should be array[i-1] = x; Else  array subscript will go out of bound.

Comment: Get used to `for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)` in C++. Otherwise you will always trip over the 0-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Get used to always initialising your variables. In this case you use `n` before it is written first time.

```
int x=1,min=1001,n=0;
```

Also heed the hint by seccpur (alternatively mine) from comments.
Here is mine again, for making a complete answer:
Get used to `for(int i=0;i<arraysize;i++)` in C++. Otherwise you will always trip over the 0-indexing.

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
```

Both problems together cause your problem of outputting the weird index (from non-initialised `n`) and the implausible value 0 (from non-initialised `array[0]`).
With your way of random numbers, 0 is impossible, but if it happens to be in index 0, then it will be the lowest of all and never be replaced by anything meangingful.

You got "lucky" (actually I consider it unlucky not being told about this kind of error...) with accessing beyond the array...